# Which devices are the set of six generalized densities used for?

Tags: android, size, screen, android-screen-support

The set of six generalized densities:

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dp
```

From my understanding:

```
ldpi = Android watch wearable size devices?
mdpi = small/medium sized Android Phones
hdpi= Larger Android phones and small Android tablets
xhdpi = Medium sized and Large Android Tablets
xxhdpi = what for?
xxxhdpi = what for?
```

I want to create my app to work on Android phones and tablets only. So should I just create images in mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi only and ignore the rest?

Comment: "From my understanding" -- none of that is correct. Any density can be used on any screen size. See [the device dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) for a table outlining the mix of screen sizes and densities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dpi has nothing to do about the physical screen size but it is all about the ***screen density***.

DPI means for *DOT PER INCH* which mean that how many pixels there is in an inch.

Right now there is no device with ldpi and mdpi out there in the market anymore. My suggestion is to prepare ***all the images*** in **xhdpi** (x2) and if any specific image appears to not clear enough in high density phone, for example, Samsung Galaxy S8, xxhdpi one may be needed for that image as well.

Comment: I'm glad I asked and thanks for clarifying everything.